# Site is breaking in iphone safari, mozilla 5 and google chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser

**A site im working on is breaking in these browsers but working fine in other browsers**?

vista home edition with mozilla 5.0

Windows XP with mozilla 5.0

iphone with privately

iphone with safari

Vista with Google chrome 5.0.1

**But working fine in:**

ie 8 and 7 on a PC,

safari, firefox and chrome on the mac

Check it: http://millcreek-cycles.jmdw.stackablehost.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is class called **#header div** in master.css
remove **max-width** from this class.

Since IE does not understand max-width this renders correctly in IE

Answer (score 0):

Chrome dev console gives the following error:

```
Unmatched </p> encountered.  Converting </p> into <p></p>.
```

http://validator.w3.org reveals many more errors, any one of which could be causing the display problem. For example, you have `</html></body></html>`.